# How to get facebook comments, likes, and share count for post which is shared by user?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I have used following url to get count;

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20total_count,comment_count,like_count,share_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://buff.ly/1mtu81f%27

This gives me result like;

{

```
"data": [
    {
        "total_count": 95,
        "comment_count": 6,
        "like_count": 24,
        "share_count": 65
    }
]
```

}

This result is giving me global count but I need count for only url which is shared by me & present on my facebook dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you'll have to query the stream FQL table (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/). Therefore, you'll need a "read_stream" permission.

Try this:

```
select post_id, like_info, comment_info, share_info from stream where source_id=me() and attachment.href = "http://buff.ly/1mtu81f"
```

Comment: I have tried the query but I got response like;
{

    "error": {
        "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ",
        "type": "NoIndexFunctionException",
        "code": 604
    }

}

Comment: If you use the exact query there shouldn't be a problem. Just tried it again and it works! The field "source_id" is indexable, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/